# TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

My code is running fine on python 2.x versions but when I'm trying to run it on python 3.x version, it's giving error.

subject: need to abbreviate any message in sms encoding.

Code:

```
def sms_encoding(data):
    #start writing your code here
    print(data)
    data.split(" ")
    data_list=data.split(" ")
    sms_encd=[]
    final_sms=""
    for i in range(len(data_list)):
        if data_list[i].lower() in  ['a','e','i','o','u']:
            sms_encd.append(data_list[i])
        elif len(data_list[i])>1:
            a = data_list[i].translate(None,'aeiouAEIOU')
            sms_encd.append(a)
    for j in range(len(sms_encd)):
        final_sms += str(sms_encd[j])+" "
    return final_sms[:-1]
data="I will not repeat mistakes"
print(sms_encoding(data))
```

Output:

2.x versions:

```
I will not repeat mistakes
I wll nt rpt mstks
```

3.x versions:

```
I will not repeat mistakes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 18, in <module>
  File "python", line 12, in sms_encoding
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

why `translate()` is not working? is there any alternative workaround?

Comment: apologies folks, I could not find the existing question. thanks you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to compare Python 3's `str.translate()` with Python 2's `unicode.translate()`. Both take a *mapping* from codepoint (an integer) to a replacement (either another integer or a single-character Unicode e string).

The `str` type has a static method [`str.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) that takes the characters-to-delete (the second argument to Python 2's `str.translate()`) as the third argument, to produce such a map. Use that here:

```
map = str.maketrans('', '', 'aeiouAEIOU')
a = data_list[i].translate(map)
```

This outputs a dictionary mapping each of the vowel codepoints to `None`:

```
>>> str.maketrans('', '', 'aeiouAEIOU')
{97: None, 101: None, 105: None, 111: None, 117: None, 65: None, 69: None, 73: None, 79: None, 85: None}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Martijn Pieters.