# string.translate() does not accept 2 args

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have looked at several answers on
[Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)
but none of these seem to address my problem. I am trying to strip punctuation from a string using string.translate().

When I run the code:

```
import string
s = "This. has? punctuation," 
noPunct = s.translate(s.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
```

I get:

```
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Is this perhaps an issue with the python version I am using? I am using python 3.5.4 for compatibility with nltk. Otherwise I am stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python 3 interface for `str.translate` uses a mapping.  Make one with `str.maketrans`:

```
>>> import string
>>> table = str.maketrans({}.fromkeys(string.punctuation))
>>> "This. has? punctuation,".translate(table)
'This has punctuation'
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using Python 2.x code, but running Python 3.x. Scroll down on the linked question to see how to do it in Python 3.x:

```
s.translate(mapping)
```

Answer (score 0):

Different function signatures between [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Similar questions have been asked here:

- [TypeError - Translate takes one argument.(2 given) Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23175809/typeerror-translate-takes-one-argument-2-given-python)
- [translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given) in python error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375712/translate-takes-exactly-one-argument-2-given-in-python-error)
- [TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576845/typeerror-translate-takes-exactly-one-argument-2-given)
- [translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312108/translate-takes-exactly-one-argument-2-given)
- [Error: TypeError: translate() takes one argument (2 given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792038/error-typeerror-translate-takes-one-argument-2-given)